# Turnkey CDN solutions?

Tags: c#, cdn

I have a C# application that generates simple JPEG images. I need to be able to store these images and recall them at various times in the future. So, I'm looking for a turnkey, secure, CDN system. I have hacked my own together with a Windows server and IIS - I upload via FTP and request images over HTTP - but (1) there's, effectively, no need for it to be Windows and (2) its not very cost effective. I'll be generating approximately 1-2GB of images each month and I need to hold the images in perpetuity.

What are some of the turnkey options for storing this many images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest storing the images on [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). It's stable, widely supported, and can plug into a variety of workflows and security models. As of August 2011, pricing starts at $0.09/GB/month for storage, and $0.12/GB for transfer (with the first GB per month free).

While many people use S3 as a cheap and good-enough CDN, Amazon also offers [Amazon Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/), a "real" CDN that integrates neatly with S3.

Amazon maintains an official C# library that can talk to S3 and CloudFront, the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of NetDNA  http://www.netdna.com/ . I currently use them - good customer service, and inexpensive.  Also, it is easy to plugin into Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Amazon Cloudfront http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

It's their CDN product built on S3. You can use the available C# libraries, examples here http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-S3/129